# Как из плагина передать данные в окно Editor

Tags: unity3d, плагин

Делаю плагин для Unity3D, есть потребность выводить данные в форму по событию, то бишь хочу когда событие наступило запустить некий код с логикой в окне Editor. Как мне сделать вызов метода если из плагина я не могу видеть классы в папке Plugins/Editor.

Answer (score 1):

- Если вопрос вообще в callback'ах из плагина - то есть топик с примером кода [на форуме Unity](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/communicating-c-with-c.89930/).
- Если вопрос в доступе к классам в папках `Editor` из runtime-скриптов, то это невозможно, так как скрипты редактора [компилируются позже](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html). Но, можно вынести необходимые скрипты из папки `Editor` в runtime и просто обернуть их в `#if UNITY_EDITOR ... #endif`.